# Probability of apple

Tags: probability

4 out of 15 apples are rotten.What is the probability that 9th apple will be rotten if the apples are not replaced after being inspected?

P.S.:if I had to find probability that all four are defective then I would have done something like: $4/15 \times 3/14 \times 2/12 \times1/11  $ 
How to implement the additional constraint?

Comment: Hint:  you know the answer for the first apple, yes?  What is the probability that the second is rotten?  The third?  You should spot a pattern.

Comment: @lulu but probability that 9th will be rotten seems little strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider that each of the apples has the same probability for being the ninth apple drawn, and $4$ among the $15$ are rotten .

Comment: so how do I proceed with it?

Answer (score 0):

Let the rotten apples be labelled $R$ and non-rotten apples be labelled $N.$ The probability that $9th$ apple is rotten is equal to the probability of placing the letters $N$ and $R$ in 9 blanks such that the $9th$ blank is $R.$ $$\_ \cdot\_ \cdot\_\cdot\_ \cdot\_\cdot\_\cdot\_\cdot\_\cdot R$$

The possibilities are $$4R\text{ and }5N\\3R\text{ and }6N\\2R\text{ and }7N\\1R\text{ and }8N$$

In the first case, one $R$ is fixed and the other the blanks for the rest of the three $R$ can be chosen in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways. Thus, the probability becomes $$\binom{8}{3}\frac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{15\cdot14\cdots7}$$
In the second case, one $R$ is fixed and the other blanks for the rest of the two $R$ can be chosen in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways. Thus, the probability becomes 
$$\binom{8}{2}\frac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6}{15\cdot14\cdots7}$$
Similarly, probability in the third case is 
$$\binom{8}{1}\frac{4\cdot3\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5}{15\cdot14\cdots7}$$
Finally, probability in the fourth case is 
$$\binom{8}{0}\frac{4\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}{15\cdot14\cdots7}$$

Adding the above four expressions, gives the required result.